# Can you scope CSS files so that they only apply to the descendants of a given element?

Tags: css

Given a css file, is there a way to scope the entire file so that it only applies to elements within a given element:

e.g. given:

```
<div id="container">
   <span class="some_element"/>
   <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Is there a way to scope an entire css file to apply to all elements within "container" without prepending `#container` to every single css clause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’m afraid not. Some CSS pre-processors allow you to write code that achieves the same thing though.

E.g. [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) implements nested rules:

```
/* This LESS code... */

#header {
  h1 {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  p { font-size: 12px;
    a { text-decoration: none;
      &:hover { border-width: 1px }
    }
  }
}

/* ...produces this CSS */

#header h1 {
  font-size: 26px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#header p {
  font-size: 12px;
}
#header p a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
#header p a:hover {
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

And [Andy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7841172/scoping-css-files/7841203#7841203) mentioned [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/), which does the same thing.

Comment: You can do this in-browser using [LESS's demo](http://leafo.net/lessphp/#demo). Just paste in your CSS and wrap it with your selector, e.g., `#your-custom-scope-selector { /* CSS here */ }`, click `Compile`, and you'll have your custom scoped CSS. Useful if you just need a one-time transformation and don't have LESS or SCSS on your machine.

Comment: Of course this kind of "scoping" is not going to work on rules applied to container elements outside your host element. I.e., if the source CSS file has `body {font-family: Georgia;}`, and you change it to `#your-custom-scope-selector body {font-family: Georgia;}`, that rule is going to stop working (assuming #your-custom-scope-selector is somewhere *inside* the body element; in the OP's scenario, this sounds like the case)

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `scoped` attribute on a `<style>` element, although there's little to no browser support for it. In your example:

```
<div id="container">
    <style scoped>.some_element{}</style>
    <span class="some_element"></span>
</div>
```

Here's a jQuery Polyfill: http://thingsinjars.com/post/360/scoped-style/

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 ways you could approach this:

1) In HTML5, (not widely supported yet) there is to be a `scoped` attribute you can put on a `<style>` tag. [Here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/scoped-styles-html5/) is a brief article on the subject.

2) You could use a dynamic stylesheet language (like [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/)) that allow you to nest related CSS rules together.

Comment: #1 got my hopes up but NO, it is only in HTML5.1 draft, not in HTML5 spec, and only works on firefox currently so currenly #2 is the only way to go

Answer (score 3):

Not with CSS alone, but you can use Sass, which compiled into CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You could use BEM naming notation -- http://csswizardry.com/2013/01/mindbemding-getting-your-head-round-bem-syntax/ ("block, element, modifier").

Your example would become:

```
<div id="container">
   <span class="container__some_element"/>
   <!-- etc -->
</div>
```

Yes, if you don't use an abbreviation, you're writing the same number of characters in your CSS... but your styles will have less [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) -- which can be beneficial.

Hopefully browser support for `<style scoped>` will get better in the coming years!

Answer (score -1):

You could load the page in with php and throw whatever tag you want in dynamically, or do the same with javascript/jQuery... although that's fairly clumsy.  There's no built in method to do this as CSS is always applied to the entire page.