# Using specific CSS style link with individual div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap Carousel menu which uses the following **Link 1**:

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

See **Code 1:**

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
```

It works perfectly, however, I want to incorporate this into a project I'm already working on. Which uses the following **Link 2**:

```
<link href="static/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

I want it so that **Code 1** uses **Link 1**, and the rest of the code in my project uses **Link 2**. I believe this is necessary because there are conflicting class names.

How might this be achieved.

Thanks for any help, hugely appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit scope of external css to only a specific element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667874/limit-scope-of-external-css-to-only-a-specific-element)

Comment: I believe this can help you? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667874/limit-scope-of-external-css-to-only-a-specific-element

Comment: It's not really feasible as you describe it. What's the problem? Two different Bootstrap versions?

Comment: Yes, 2 different bootstraps I believe. I think the scopes might work. Why is it not feasible?