# How to avoid bootstrap css overriding the custom css?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a custom css which looks as follows for a html page exactly as per [this](https://www.queness.com/resources/html/simple-portfolio-page/index.html) example, lets say `index.html`:

```
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, Verdana;
    background: #efefef url('../img/ticks.png') repeat 0 0;
    margin:15px 0 0 0;
    font-size:12px;
}


.container { 
    position: relative; 
    width: 960px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;  
}

#filters {
    margin:1%;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}

    #filters li {
        float:left;
    }

    #filters li span {
        display: block;
        padding:5px 20px;       
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#666;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    #filters li span.active {
        background: #e95a44;
        color:#fff;
    }



#portfoliolist .portfolio {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    width:23%;
    margin:1%;
    display:none;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
}

    .portfolio-wrapper {
        overflow:hidden;
        position: relative !important;
        background: #666;
        cursor:pointer;
    }

    .portfolio img {
        max-width:100%;
        position: relative;
        top:0;
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    transition:         all 600ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);     
    }

    .portfolio .label {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height:40px;
        bottom:-40px;
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    transition:         all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
    }

        .portfolio .label-bg {
            background: #e95a44;
            width: 100%;
            height:100%;
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
        }

        .portfolio .label-text {
            color:#fff;
            position: relative;
            z-index:500;
            padding:5px 8px;
        }

            .portfolio .text-category {
                display:block;
                font-size:9px;
            }

    .portfolio:hover .label {
    bottom:0;
  }
    .portfolio:hover img {
    top:-30px;
  }  





/* #Tablet (Portrait) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    .container {
        width: 768px; 
    }
}


/*  #Mobile (Portrait) - Note: Design for a width of 320px */
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container { 
        width: 95%; 
    }

    #portfoliolist .portfolio {
        width:48%;
        margin:1%;
    }       

    #ads {
        display:none;
    }

}


/* #Mobile (Landscape) - Note: Design for a width of 480px */
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    .container {
        width: 70%;
    }

    #ads {
        display:none;
    }

}

/* #Clearing */

/* Self Clearing Goodness */
.container:after { content: "\0020"; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility: hidden; }

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after,
.row:before,
.row:after {
  content: '\0020';
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0; }
.row:after,
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both; }
.row,
.clearfix {
  zoom: 1; }

.clear {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

To match the template of `index.html` with rest of the pages of the website (which is completely dependent on bootstrap css and independent of this css), especially to the header and footer part, I added the following lines to the header field of `index.html`

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-jhdkjsahd#SomeRandomCheckSumProvidedByBootstrap#asjdhasdkjhsdkj" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

This alters the actual behavior from the following

[image: normal]

to something like this

[image]

where the text on hover disappears.

The html code of the above element is as follows:

```
<div class="portfolio logo" data-cat="logo">
                <div class="portfolio-wrapper">             
                    <img src="img/portfolios/logo/5.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="label">
                        <div class="label-text">
                            <a class="text-title">Bird Document</a>
                            <span class="text-category">Logo</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="label-bg"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I use the boostrap css only for header and footer of `index.html` page, and hence, I tried to use `<style scoped>` tag as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17668004/2888239), but I am afraid that it is not a good way of dealing with this.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Instead of doing scoped, you can inspect the element and show the hierarchy of inheritance, so that we can change the rule to match the specificity. Is it possible to make a demo of it so that we can check if we can help you in correcting the specificity?

Comment: Sorry, I am super bad with css. I took the example from https://www.queness.com/resources/html/simple-portfolio-page/index.html and added the line ```<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-jhdkjsahd#SomeRandomCheckSumProvidedByBootstrap#asjdhasdkjhsdkj" crossorigin="anonymous">``` to the header. So thats the demo, you can check. Thank you.

Comment: Place the bootstrap `css` file above your custom `css` file.

Comment: @RichardMauritz That didn't solve the issue. I already tried.

Comment: @kingmakerking Can you show us a demo in [JSBin](http://jsbin.com)?

Comment: @PraveenKumar here it is https://jsbin.com/xacuduweka/1/edit?html,css,output. But like I said, it is easy to download the acutual folder from queness.com/resources/html/simple-portfolio-page/index.html and add the line <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> to it

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't think you can see it in the demo. Can you?

Comment: @kingmakerking Yea, kinda tough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the actual code its impossible to give you an actual markup for your situation.  However, at the root of the problem is **Specificity**.  You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Basically, the more selectors you use in your CSS, the higher it will rank in specificity.  For example, referencing your HTML above,

```
.text-title {}
```

is not very specific.

```
.label-text .text-title {}
```

is more specific and will take precedence.

```
.label .label-text .text-title {}
```

is even more specific. And:

```
div.label > .label-text > .text-title {}
```

is yet even *more* specific and will take precedence over all the others.

So the solution to the problem is that your CSS needs to get more specific than the Boostrap CSS.  Inspect the problem elements in the browser and see what selectors Bootstrap is using.  Then use more specific ones in your custom CSS.

Unfortunately, Bootstrap uses `!important` in a number of situations, so you will be forced to use it as well to over ride theirs.

Comment: Useful thing to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with what you are trying to do and finally solved it by setting the display property of the label div to block. I also noticed that chrome automatically fixes the issue contrary to Safari.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is that you can add strong text `!important` in each attribute of your code in CSS.

I Found that to be the most useful and easiest solution.

Comment: I don't think this is a good solution. CSS means cascading, using !important on everything beats some of the purpose.

Answer (score -1):

You can add **!important** after each style in your class. Adding **!important** basically will give the **CSS** more **priority/weigh**t which allows you to override other styles.

OR you can do this with-

Link your **custom.css** file should be the **last entry** below the bootstrap.css. Custom.css style will override bootstrap.css

Ex Html:-