# Padding Overwriting Later Padding

Tags: html, css

quick question about my stylesheet. I was always taught that CSS overwrites up to down. So something on line 1 could be overwritten by something on line 10. I'm trying to increase the padding in a section, but not touch the other style:

This is on Line 642

```
&:first-of-type > div {
        padding-top: 10px;
        img {
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
}
```

This is on Line 722

```
.apiPT {
    padding-top: 32px;
}
```

I don't even want to mention that I don't believe my HTML should be picking up the style from 642, but it is and it's being overwritten by it. I really would love to avoid using `!important` as that's obviously not too good. But not really sure why I'm having this issue...

```
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-5 apiPT">
                <ul class="pipe">
                    <li><a href="api-reference/v3">API references</a></li>
                </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `:first-of-type > div` has higher specificity than `.apiPT` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity depending on the rest of your markup, you could change `.apiPT` to `:first-of-type .apiPT` but there are a bunch of ways to fix it and how you should fix it depends on how the rest of your markup and css are structured

Comment: try giving an id to that particular element and then set its properties

Comment: Check out my answer on specificity to this question.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542922/how-to-avoid-bootstrap-css-overriding-the-custom-css/43544654#43544654

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid bootstrap css overriding the custom css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43542922/how-to-avoid-bootstrap-css-overriding-the-custom-css)

Comment: @sn3ll The extra classes in front did it, so for my case: .row .card .apiPT gave it higher priority - thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign an id tag to the link if it is the only link there

```
<a href="api-reference/v3" id="example" >API references</a>
```

That would overwrite it

Comment: Have too many instances on multiple pages, so not going to use an ID - thanks though

Answer (score 0):

The answer is just as @sn3ll said:

```
.class1 .class2 .apiPT {
  ...
}
```

gave it a higher priority - thanks for the help!