# How to integrate Gantt Oracle Jet Chart in Oracle Apex 5.1?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, gantt-chart, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-jet

Does anyone know how to integrate the Oracle Jet Gantt chart into Oracle Apex version 5.1? The research I have done shows either how to integrate Jet components into version 5.0 (but to my understanding, a lot changed between versions 5.0 and 5.1, specifically with regards to the Oracle JET library) or how to integrate a couple of different Oracle Jet components into Apex 5.1, but the code used to integrate these components seems very specific to the components being integrated. I have tried copying and pasting the javascript code and the HTML code from the Oracle Jet Cookbook into the the appropriate sections in the Page Designer on Apex, but nothing shows up when I run the page. Specifically, I'm wondering how to use the Oracle Jet cookbook code for the Gantt chart to create that Gantt chart on a page in my Apex application?

Has anyone tried to do this yet?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not find a plugin, you can use oracle-jet gantt by making direct references using a CDN to the files on your apex page.

1 - First upload the main.js file to the shared components of your application. He must follow these guidelines https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/jet400/jet/developer/GUID-219A636B-0D0B-4A78-975B-0528497A82DD.htm#JETDG-GUID-219A636B-0D0B-4A78-975B-0528497A82DD

Your main.js look like this:

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

function _getCDNPath(paths) {
    var cdnPath = "";
    var ojPath = "";
    var thirdpartyPath = "";
    var keys = Object.keys(paths);
    var newPaths = {};
    function _isoj(key) {
        return (key.indexOf('oj') === 0 && key !== 'ojdnd');
    }
    keys.forEach(function(key) {
        newPaths[key] = cdnPath + (_isoj(key) ? ojPath : thirdpartyPath) + paths[key];
    });
    return newPaths;
}

require.config({
    paths: _getCDNPath({
        'knockout': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/knockout/knockout-3.4.0',
        'jquery': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/jquery/jquery-3.1.1.min',
        'jqueryui-amd': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/jquery/jqueryui-amd-1.12.0.min',
        'ojs': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/default/js/min',
        'ojL10n': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/default/js/ojL10n',
        'ojtranslations': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/default/js/resources',
        'text': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/require/text',
        'promise': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/es6-promise/es6-promise.min',
        'hammerjs': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/hammer/hammer-2.0.8.min',
        'signals': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/js-signals/signals.min',
        'ojdnd': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/dnd-polyfill/dnd-polyfill-1.0.0.min',
        'css': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/require-css/css.min',
        'customElements': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/webcomponents/custom-elements.min',
        'proj4js': 'https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/proj4js/dist/proj4'
    })
})

requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '',
    // Path mappings for the logical module names
    paths: {
    },
    // Shim configurations for modules that do not expose AMD
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: ['jQuery', '$']
        },
        'maps': {
            deps: ['jquery', 'i18n'],
        }
    },
    // This section configures the i18n plugin. It is merging the Oracle JET built-in translation
    // resources with a custom translation file.
    // Any resource file added, must be placed under a directory named "nls". You can use a path mapping or you can define
    // a path that is relative to the location of this main.js file.
    config: {
        ojL10n: {
            merge: {
                //'ojtranslations/nls/ojtranslations': 'resources/nls/menu'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

2 - Now you need to load this file (main.js) and require.js on your page. Use the "File URLs" field for this.
require.js: https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/3rdparty/require/require.js

[image]

3 - In the header of your page you need to include this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="css" href="https://static.oracle.com/cdn/jet/v4.0.0/default/css/alta/oj-alta-min.css">
<script>
        if (!document.createElement) {
          document.createElement = document.constructor.prototype.createElement;
          document.createElementNS = document.constructor.prototype.createElementNS;
          document.importNode = document.constructor.prototype.importNode;
        }

        // The "oj_whenReady" global variable enables a strategy that the busy context whenReady,
        // will implicitly add a busy state, until the application calls applicationBoostrapComplete
        // on the busy state context.
        window["oj_whenReady"] = true;
</script>
```

[image]

4 - Create a region to place the html of your oracle-jet chart
[image]

5 - Finally, create a dynamic action to effectively create your gantt chart. The dynamic action event is page loading. It should run a javascript code. This code is the file demo.js on cookbook site.

[image]

---

Ex. https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=145794:23

login on: https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=4550

```
workspace: stackquestions
user: test
pwd: test
app: 145794
page: 23
```

---

Once you make this work, your problem will be how to get the data and update the gantt depending on some filters. I suggest creating a restful service to get this data from your tables. For this you will need some javascript handling to make your data follow the format expected by oracle-jet. You can see the expected format in the ganttData.json file.

Good luck.

---

I noticed that the css file needed to make the oracle-jet work interferes with the page's css. I tried to use this idea [Limit scope of external css to only a specific element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667874/limit-scope-of-external-css-to-only-a-specific-element) but it did not work completely.

Comment: Thank you so much, @romeuBraga!!!! Your post was so incredibly helpful. I really appreciate all of your efforts!

Comment: Apparently the new version of apex will have the oracle-jet gantt chart. https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-18.1/HTMRN/toc.htm#HTMRN-GUID-3D0E0D99-99E9-484B-8923-4BEDB2A86EBE

Answer (score 1):

why just not take a plugin ? either write your own or look at apex.world for the gantt plugin

Comment: I would like to use a plugin, but I can't find any that meet my specific needs. I need a Gantt chart that allows for multiple child tasks in the same line, and I can't find a plugin that allows for that and I'm not familiar enough with plsql to write one myself. There is one on oracle jet that allows for multiple child tasks per line

Comment: okay and if you consider updating to 5.2 ? i think they implemented the gantt again

Comment: I appreciate the thought but unfortunately I'm required to use the version I'm currently using. Not allowed to upgrade

Comment: okay the only more thing i know would be downloading the gantt from apex.world and adapt it. Even with little PL/SQL skills you can do that. Thats how i did it

Comment: Would you mind sharing with me which gantt chart you downloaded from apex.world? And are you saying you were able to specifically adapt it so that the gantt chart you downloaded could handle multiple child tasks per row?

Comment: https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:7012480178878::::P710_PLG_ID:COM.GITHUB.OGOBRECHT.DHTMLXGANTT i was able to adapt it yes

Comment: Thank you @oracletest for your help. Just to clarify, you're saying you were able to adapt this plugin so that the chart can handle multiple child tasks per row? I just want to make sure that's what you meant when you said that that's what you did.