# How can I limit the scope of Materialize CSS in Wordpress?

Tags: css, wordpress, materialize

I have a Materialize menu that i use in other areas of my website and i tried to import it into Wordpress. With a few edits its been successful and the menu is running fine. you can see it working [here](http://news.focallocal.org)

The issue i'm having now is that the external css called to use Materialize has overridden of the css in wordpress/my theme.

Does anyone know how to limit the Materilize css to one element on a website, in this case it'd be my menu div.

here's the scripts i called to get Materialize to work. I found that i had to make small edits to the menu which was built for a standard html page, but nothing too significant, other than calling these scripts. ja little trial and error needed to get to where i am now.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

edit: this question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667874/limit-scope-of-external-css-to-only-a-specific-element) because scoped css is depreciated (the 1st answer), and i can't wrap it in the div in my css file as the css being called is an external one, quite a large one, from Materialize (the second answer)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit scope of external css to only a specific element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667874/limit-scope-of-external-css-to-only-a-specific-element)

Comment: I can't help but say... but it seems simple to re-create this menu - especially now that you have some source code to reference?

Comment: i'm not a particularly good developer. i had a recreation i made on that page before but it had a few issues and didn't look exactly the same without calling the materialize css. i decided to try and get the same menu working on each page across the website. i'm working on individual fixes, i was just hoping someone here knew how to stop that css file from interring sitewide on a wordpress install.

anyway, my situation doesn't change that the question might be useful for others who have issue with externally loaded css in the future