# Loading external css file in a specific div

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to load an external file named for `//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css` in a specific div with its id named for `registerForm`.

Here are my code snippets as shown below.

**html side**

```
<div id="registerForm">
        <style scoped>
            @import "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css";
        </style>
   ...
   </div>
```

This css file cannot implement in the specific div. It just covers all html code effects other divs.

I also tried this method shown below but nothing changed.

```
<style type="text/css" scoped="true">
            @import url('${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.min.css');
        </style>


<script
    src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/jquery.scoped.js"></script>
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Looks like there are callbacks for success and error states; you should at least have a callback for the error state to see if there's something there. Also, if you're posting someone else's code, you should at least give a link back to their site so they get credit...

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667874/limit-scope-of-external-css-to-only-a-specific-element ?

Comment: dota2pro,Heretic Monkey  I changed the post.

Comment: AFAIK no browser supports the `scoped` attribute and it shouldn't be used.

Comment: This is a completely different question. [The `scoped` attribute was deprecated a while ago](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLStyleElement/scoped). See also [browser support for `scoped`](https://caniuse.com/#feat=style-scoped). AFAIK there is no way of pulling in an external file and applying to only one element in a document without rewriting the CSS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit scope of external css to only a specific element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17667874/limit-scope-of-external-css-to-only-a-specific-element)

Comment: I looked many suggesstion to solve it out but I cannot reach the right result.