# Apply Jquery CSS For Specific Div Only

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to apply jquery Css Library for an specific `<div>` only rather than whole page as it is messing my whole page while applying. Below is the css I have tried but it is yet applying to whole page

```
#myPopup3{
@include '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">';
}
```

how to apply the link only for `#myPopup3` `<div>`

Comment: You can try: `@include 'https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css';`

Comment: css not loading with this

Comment: Refer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/17668004/5474196

Comment: ok tried but not working with this too

Comment: <style scoped>
               @include '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">';
          </style>
    
                    <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup3" class="ui-content">
                                <p>I will appear directly over the clicked link.</p>
                     </div>

Comment: Try with `<style scoped> @include 'https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css'; </style> <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup3" class="ui-content"> <p>I will appear directly over the clicked link.</p> </div> `

Comment: tried css not loading

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div>
      <style scoped>
        @import "https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css";
      </style>
      <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup3" class="ui-content">
        <p>I will appear directly over the clicked link.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: working but css applying to whole page which i am trying to avoid