# Link external CSS file only for specific Div

Tags: html, css

I need to link external CSS file for specific DIV

i have 3 external CSS file

```
main.css
bootstrap.css
style.css
```

I need to link the `style.css`file to specific div `<div class="leftmenu">`
how do i link to that div

how do i link the `style.css` file to  `<div class="leftmenu">`

style.css

```
ul
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
list-style-type:none;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; backface-visibility: hidden;  
}
.var_nav
{
position:relative;
background:#ccc; 
width:300px;
height:70px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
.link_bg
{
width:70px;
height:70px;
position:absolute;
background:#E01B6A;
color:#fff;
z-index:2;
}
.link_bg i
{
    position:relative;
}
.link_title
{
position:absolute;
width:100%;
z-index:3;
color:#fff;
}
.link_title:hover .icon
{
-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
-o-transform:rotate(360deg);
-ms-transform:rotate(360deg);
transform:rotate(360deg);  
}
.var_nav:hover .link_bg
{
width:100%;
background:#E01B6A;
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;  
}
.var_nav:hover a
{
font-weight:bold;
-webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out; 
-o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out; 
-ms-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
transition:all .5s ease-in-out;  
}
.icon
{
position:relative;
width:70px;
height:70px;
text-align:center;
color:#fff;
-webkit-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition:all .5s ease-in-out; 
-o-transition:all .5s ease-in-out; 
-ms-transition:all .5s ease-in-out;   
float:left;
transition:all .5s ease-in-out;   
float:left;  
}
.icon i{top:22px;position:relative;}
a{
display:block;
position:absolute;
float:left;
font-family:arial;
color:#fff;
text-decoration:none;
width:100%;
height:70px;
text-align:center;
}
span
{
margin-top:25px;
display:block;
}
```

i have checked the following link [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16356939/div-with-external-stylesheet) but its little had to know can some one help me how do i link css file to a div

```
<head>
<link href="../fonticon/flaticon.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

Comment: @webeno i need to link file to one specific div

Comment: how do you call `style.css` on your file where you have `<div class="leftmenu">`? can you paste that part of your `head` into your original question?

Comment: @webeno check my question i have added and read my question i need to link entire CSS file to only one div i entire page

Comment: from this folder structure, i'm assuming that your `style.css` file is in the same folder as the file you have this `head` on, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62694/discussion-between-sanoj-lawrence-and-webeno).

Comment: There is no way to "link a css file to a specific div". You can make the css in `style.css` apply only to a certain div using selectors, but your question, as stated, makes no sense.

Comment: ...and why are you inviting me for chat when then you're not answering...?

Comment: Please don't post huge amounts of irrelevant CSS.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Other ideas:

#### Use CSS preprocessor

```
.leftmenu {
    @include 'style.css';
}
```

This uses the nesting capability of CSS preprocessors to pre-qualify all the rules in `style.css`. Replace the `@include` with your favorite preprocessor's directive for bringing in another CSS file.

#### Rewrite CSS manually

You can "namespace" the rules in `style.css` by changing all the selectors to be preceded by a qualifyng `.leftmenu`.

#### Rewrite CSS automatically

You could write JS code to rewrite the stylesheet selectors at run-time to prefix the selectors with the class name, which his essentially what this plug-in does: https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin. Or you could do this rewriting on the server, whatever language it's written in.

#### Use `IFRAME` as sandbox

If the content of the thing you want to apply the styles to can be placed in an iframe, you could add the `style.css` frame to the HTML loaded in the iframe.

That's about it.

Comment: Yes these are the best options for specific div/ section for styling with external CSS. I done using CSS Preprocessor(SASS) for rewrite CSS and include in my existing project.